# ValueError: The two structures don't have the same sequence length. Input structure has length 1, while shallow structure has length 2

Tags: tensorflow, input, structure

What is the solution to the following error in tensorflow.

> ValueError: The two structures don't have the same sequence length.
> Input structure has length 1, while shallow structure has length 2.

I tried tensorflow versions:  2.9.1 and 2.4.0.
**The toy example is given to reproduce the error.**

```
import tensorflow as tf
d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
d1 = d1.map(lambda x:tf.cast([x], tf.float32))
def func1(x):
    y1 = 2.0 * x
    y2 = -3.0 * x
    return tuple([y1, y2])
d2 = d1.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func1, [x], [tf.float32, tf.float32]))
d3 = d2.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=(None,))
for x, y in d2.as_numpy_iterator(): 
    pass
```

The full error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/pythonProject/tfProjects/asr/transformer/dataset.py in <module>
      256     return tuple([y1, y2])
      257 d2 = d1.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func1, [x], [tf.float32, tf.float32]))
---> 258 d3 = d2.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=(None,))
     259 for x, y in d2.as_numpy_iterator():
     260     pass

~/miniconda3/envs/jtf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in padded_batch(self, batch_size, padded_shapes, padding_values, drop_remainder, name)
   1887         padding_values,
   1888         drop_remainder,
-> 1889         name=name)
   1890 
   1891   def map(self,

~/miniconda3/envs/jtf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, batch_size, padded_shapes, padding_values, drop_remainder, name)
   5171 
   5172     input_shapes = get_legacy_output_shapes(input_dataset)
-> 5173     flat_padded_shapes = nest.flatten_up_to(input_shapes, padded_shapes)
   5174 
   5175     flat_padded_shapes_as_tensors = []

~/miniconda3/envs/jtf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/nest.py in flatten_up_to(shallow_tree, input_tree)
    377       `input_tree`.
    378   """
--> 379   assert_shallow_structure(shallow_tree, input_tree)
    380   return list(_yield_flat_up_to(shallow_tree, input_tree))
    381 

~/miniconda3/envs/jtf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/nest.py in assert_shallow_structure(shallow_tree, input_tree, check_types)
    290     if len(input_tree) != len(shallow_tree):
    291       raise ValueError(
--> 292           "The two structures don't have the same sequence length. Input "
    293           f"structure has length {len(input_tree)}, while shallow structure "
    294           f"has length {len(shallow_tree)}.")

ValueError: The two structures don't have the same sequence length. Input structure has length 1, while shallow structure has length 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following modification in padded_shapes argument will resolve the error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
d1 = d1.map(lambda x:tf.cast([x], tf.float32))
def func1(x):
    y1 = 2.0 * x
    y2 = -3.0 * x
    return tuple([y1, y2])
d2 = d1.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func1, [x], [tf.float32, tf.float32]))
d3 = d2.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=([None],[None]))
for x, y in d2.as_numpy_iterator(): 
    pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.